# what are the reserved (default, system) parameters in Power BI

Tags: parameters, powerbi, powerquery, documentation

In Power BI, or more specifically Power Query, you can setup Parameters. There are reserved / default / standard / system parameters that the Power BI engine uses, for example "RangeStart" and "RangeEnd". It seems "Environment" does something as well. However, I can't find any documentation on this subject. Does anyone know a complete list of parameters and their purpose?

Answer (score 1):

That's a misconception. "RangeStart" and "RangeEnd" are neither system parameters nor reserved words. You can use them freely for whatever you like. Only in the case that you want to configure incremental refresh you have to use these parameter names as data variables and then filter your data by that range.

I never came across an "Environment" parameter. What's your source?